# How can we check the leaderboard details in Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-api, leaderboard, google-play-games

I'm developing a casual game which has a leaderboard based on Google newly released Google Play Game Services API. What I want to know is whether there is any place to check my leaderboard stats? I want to reset them once a month so users can have a fresh start every month. 
My leaderboard is more like FourSquare leaderboard.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This from :
https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#leaderboard_time_frames

"The Google Play game services SDK automatically creates daily, weekly, and all-time versions of every leaderboard that you create. There's no need for you to create separate leaderboards for each time frame.

Daily leaderboards reset at midnight PST every day, and weekly leaderboards reset at Saturday midnight PST."

AFAIK it is not possible for you to reset your leaderboards manually, other than deleting /unpublishing them.

Comment: Once published, you won't be able to delete it anymore!